# Java 11 compile error: Package xxx exists in another module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, java-platform-module-system

There is a class in my project. This class in package javax.swing extends javax.swing.JOptionPane because I want to use some protected methods of JOptionPane.

When the compiler is JDK 8 it works fine. I update the JDK version to 11 then I've got a compile error: Package 'javax.swing' exists in another module: java.desktop.

My IDE is Intellij idea. I opened the Settings--Build,Execution,Deployment--Java Compiler and added an item to 'Override compiler parameters pre-module'. The Module is my project. The compilation options is

```
--patch-module java.desktop=src -d mypatches/java.desktop/src/java.desktop/javax/swing/Top.java
```

But it does not work.

My project tree is 'GreatProject/src/javax/swing/Top.java'.

What's the 'src -d' means?

What's the right '--patch-module'?

Comment: I'd be really curious about the methods for which you had to do this dirty hack

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Java 9 version, full support for the [jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) project was added to ensure the project's modularity. This system can cause problems at the compile process if the same names are present in packages.

- Please, check this topic about the [module patching process](https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/issues/27) to adapt your module for **javax.swing** package.
- Also, you may try to use [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for getting elements from 'JOptionPane' class.

Comment: I have seen the patch-module command in [OpenJDK website](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start). There is an example. javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base \
        src/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java. What does the backslash do? What's the mypatches?